# WebService (AsyncTask) só funciona com Debug?

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Estou fazendo meu aplicativo Android carregar dados de um WebService. Nele, vou carregar dados de datas em um Spinner e, quando estiver completo, as mesmas datas vão carregar outros tipos de dados em um ListView, mas por enquanto estou utilizando um exemplo para ver como ficou e já corrigir erros de consistência.
   Enfim, o problema é que quando faço o **AsyncTask, executuo-o e devo carregar o Spinner, o app para de funcionar**. Mas quando colocar essa parte para **debugar o programa consegue funcionar** perfeitamente.

Código java:

public class BaixarRotas extends Opcoes{

```
//OPÇÃO DO MENU
private final String NAMESPACE = "";
private final String URL = "";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "";     //Tirei estes dados por segurança
private final String METHOD_NAME = "";
private String TAG = "";

private static String resultado;
private static String WSResultado;
public List<WSGetterSetter> listaLida;

Spinner spinner_baixarrota_datas;
Button button_baixarrota_selecionar;
TextView tv;
TextView tv2;

String dataSelecionada;

String[]exemplo = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };
ListView listView_baixarrota_escolha;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.baixar_rota1);

    spinner_baixarrota_datas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_baixarrota_datas);
    button_baixarrota_selecionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_baixarrota_selecionar);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_baixarrota_resultData);
    listView_baixarrota_escolha = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_baixarrota_escolha);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_baixarrota_result);

   // início debug
   AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
    task.execute();

    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listaLida.size(); i++) mylist.add(i, listaLida.get(i).getsData());

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_datas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mylist);
    spinner_baixarrota_datas.setAdapter(spinner_datas);
    // fim debug

    // Layouts
    if(resultado == "**Registros Carregado"){
        button_baixarrota_selecionar.setEnabled(true);
        button_baixarrota_selecionar.setClickable(true);

        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,exemplo);
        listView_baixarrota_escolha.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
    else {
        button_baixarrota_selecionar.setEnabled(false);
        button_baixarrota_selecionar.setClickable(false);

        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    //escolhendo a data
    spinner_baixarrota_datas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            dataSelecionada = spinner_baixarrota_datas.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        }

    });
    // escolhe o item do listView
    listView_baixarrota_escolha.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            AlertDialog alerta;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaixarRotas.this);
            builder.setTitle("Confirmar escolha:");
            builder.setMessage("-DATA: "+ dataSelecionada +"\n-ROTA: " + "\n-ATIVIDADE: " + "\n-RESPONSÁVEL: " + "\n-QUANTIDADE: ");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            { public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                }
            });
            alerta = builder.create();
            alerta.show();
        }
    });

}
// Inutilizado, pois estou usando um exemplo logo embaixo (no AsyncTask)
public void getData() {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo dataPI = new PropertyInfo();

    dataPI.setName("DATA");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        WSResultado = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

        Log.i("t", "doInBackground");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        // getData();
        // WSResultado é um exemplo de XML e está substituindo o getData(), um dado obtido pelo o WebService
        WSResultado = "<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\" xmlns:diffgr=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\">\n" +
                "               <NewDataSet xmlns=\"\">\n" +
                "                  <Table diffgr:id=\"Table2\" msdata:rowOrder=\"1\">\n" +
                "                     <DATA>2013-08-21T00:00:00-03:00</DATA>\n" +
                "                  </Table>\n" +
                "                  <Table diffgr:id=\"Table3\" msdata:rowOrder=\"2\">\n" +
                "                     <DATA>2013-08-22T00:00:00-03:00</DATA>\n" +
                "                  </Table>\n" +
                "               </NewDataSet>\n" +
                "            </diffgr:diffgram>";

        // CHAMADA parser (analisador do Xml)
        List<WSGetterSetter> datasR = null;
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(WSResultado.getBytes());

        WSParser parser = new WSParser();
        datasR = parser.parse(is);

        listaLida = datasR;
        resultado = "**Registros Carregado";
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        tv.setText(resultado);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        tv.setText("**Carregando...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");

    }

}
```

Esta parte é onde eu tenho que colocar para debugar (principalmente na criação do Spinner):

```
    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
    task.execute();

    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listaLida.size(); i++) mylist.add(i, listaLida.get(i).getsData());

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_datas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mylist);
    spinner_baixarrota_datas.setAdapter(spinner_datas);
```

O XML deste código se necessário para melhor entendendimento:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="Data:"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff010101"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_baixarrota_datas"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Selecionar"
        android:id="@+id/button_baixarrota_selecionar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner_baixarrota_datas"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_baixarrota_datas"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="**Registros não carregado"
        android:id="@+id/textView_baixarrota_resultData"
        android:textColor="#ffff0008"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner_baixarrota_datas" />


</RelativeLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_baixarrota_datas"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ROTA -  ATIVIDADE  -  RESPONSÁVEL  -  QUANTIDADE"
        android:id="@+id/tv_tabela"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#f0b4b9b7"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="356dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView_baixarrota_escolha"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/borda"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="356dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="**Registros não carregado"
        android:id="@+id/textView_baixarrota_result"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffff0008"
        android:background="@drawable/borda"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

O logcat apresenta o seguinte erro:"Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference"
Já vi em outras perguntas, mas nenhuma foi eficiente. Então alguém tem alguma ideia que seja esse problema?
Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Apesar de não ter postado o erro tenho 99.99% de certeza que é `NullPointerException`.</s>

A razão é que a lista `listaLida` só é inicializada dentro do `doInBackground()` da *AsyncTask*.

Mas, mesmos que inicializasse a lista antes o código não iria funcionar como julga.
Nesta parte do código,

```
task.execute();

ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < listaLida.size(); i++) mylist.add(i, listaLida.get(i).getsData());
```

é mandado executar a task e de imediato se utiliza a lista que será preenchida por ela.

A task é assíncrona ou seja quando a linha `task.execute();` é executada o programa continua a execução em `ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();` sem esperar que a task termine e a lista seja preenchida.

Você deve passar todo o código que depende da lista estar preenchida para um novo método e chamá-lo no método `onPostExecute()` da *AsyncTask*.

O erro pode não acontecer durante o *debug* porque o avanço passo a passo é lento e deve dar tempo a que a lista seja preenchida antes de ser utilizada.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Eu já entendia que tava tendo um erro no processo AsyncTask e na formação do Layout, mas o problema é que o logCat apresentava o problema como: "Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference" e fiquei travado nisso... O app funcionou

Comment: O erro que indiquei não é o mesmo mas a causa é a mesma: a lista é nula quando tenta utilizá-la. Quando perguntar sobre algo em que ocorre um erro deve indicá-lo para que seja mais fácil entendermos o problema.